# Getting distributed package doesn't have mpi built in error

Tags: python, mpi, pytorch, openmpi

I have been trying to write a distributed application using pytorch. I have been following tutorial [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/dist_tuto.html). Over there, I am using the "MPI Backend" option. According to that, I need to follow the basic steps to install pytorch and then install openmpi as `conda install -c conda-forge openmpi`

Unfortunately, whenever I try to run a script using mpirun `mpiexec -n 2 python ptdist.py`, I get the following error `RuntimeError: Distributed package doesn't have MPI built in`. I believe this is happening because of error in `import ProcessGroupMPI` code [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py) in python.

I have tried to install openmpi from their [source code](http://www.open-mpi.org) as well as `sudo apt-get install python-mpi4py`, but am still facing the same error.

I also tried `pip install mpi4py` but that also does not help

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

From https://medium.com/@esaliya/pytorch-distributed-with-mpi-acb84b3ae5fd

> The MPI backend, though supported, is not available unless you compile PyTorch from its source

This suggests you should **first** install your favorite MPI library, and possibly `mpi4py` built on top of it, and then build `pytorch` from sources at last.

Comment: @Gilies I followed the same tutorial from medium to setup everything. I am getting the same aforementioned error

Comment: there is an other tutorial at https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/dist_tuto.html. I suggest you restart from a fresh install (so you do not run `python setup.py install` too early). Also check the outputs in order to confirm MPI backend is found.